# Is Nyaya Naturalistic

Tags: nyaya, nature

Wondering if Nyaya is naturalistic ie Do natural forces primarily operate in this universe? If not where would you categorize it? Are there any purely Nyaya ie uncorrupted by the Vaisheshika school of thought text which generally summarizes Nyaya based on naturalism?